# CakePHP: how to allow public access to files in a directory besides /webroot

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to be able to open pdfs that live in a folder at `/app/somefile/file.pdf` via apache like this `http://mysite/app/somefile.file.pdf`. I've tried adding a RewriteCond in CakePHP's .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/somefolder/ - [L]
```

But just get a 500 error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not a good idea to allow public access to directories other than webroot. It is not secure. You can use a controller action to download files from any location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this buy only adding this to the .htaccess file in the root:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/somefolder/`

(My original version had a `[L]` which is incorrect, and that's why it wasn't working.)

Just in case anyone doesn't already know: this is not generally a secure thing to do. I have very specific reasons for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your controller and use routes to access it the way you want, opening up other folders for the world is NOT a good idea

**Sending files**

There are times when you want to send files as responses for your requests. Prior to version 2.3 you could use [Media Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html) to accomplish that. As of 2.3 MediaView is deprecated and you can use `CakeResponse::file()` to send a file as response:

```
public function sendFile($id) {
    $file = $this->Attachment->getFile($id);
    $this->response->file($file['path']);
    //Return reponse object to prevent controller from trying to render a view
    return $this->response;
`enter code here`}
```

As shown in above example as expected you have to pass the file path to the method. CakePHP will send proper content type header if it’s a known file type listed in CakeReponse::$_mimeTypes. You can add new types prior to calling `CakeResponse::file()` by using the `CakeResponse::type()` method.

If you want you can also force a file to be downloaded instead of being displayed in the browser by specifying the options:

```
$this->response->file($file['path'], array('download' => true, 'name' => 'foo'));
```

source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Apache [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) to make the contents of that directory publicly accessible:

```
Alias /app/somefile /app/webroot/somefile
```

Place the above code in a server/virtual host config file, not .htaccess.

Make sure the web server user has read access to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

you could just make a symlink to them, though your apache config may or may not be allowed to follow them.